# Comparing 4 Databases to Distributed Database

Tags: sql-server, etl

So I have a rather unique task. I have a customer who needs to take 4 similar databases and combine into a single distributed database. Keep in mind that schemas on production DB’s change frequently (couple times a month). I have the distributed database ready and utilized Red Gate SQL Compare.

I also need to send out an email when either an error occurs such as triggers or stored procs change and need manual intervention or an actual error occurs.

However, I need to continually monitor changes and compare those schema changes regularly against the distributed database. This is due to the customer having over 100 applications that will need to have connection strings adjusted and possibly moved to a monolith.

Then comes the task of moving data to the distributed database. My boss wants to write a full .NET Win Forms app to do this. So, I suppose I’m needing to know what some options would be and if there’s a way to utilize SSDT with a .NET App to do comparisons?

Comment: Sounds like poor design if you ask me. Unfortunately this is going to be too broad for SO. SO is about answering specific technical questions, not talking through design options.

Comment: I don't know how big your database is but a poorly built integration tool (i.e. one built by a programmer in .Net) can make data transfer 100's of times slower than it needs to be.

Comment: These are older databases that the customer is using. They split it up the way the did partially because of the poor internet connectivity where the business is located. They have 4 locations. But I do agree that .NET apps will slow things down. If SO isn’t appropriate where would be a more appropriate place? SQLServerCentral?

Comment: If you have SQL Compare already, can't you use the SQL Compare command line to run the comparisons?